# How to run Clean and Rerun in Android Studio from keyboard shortcut

Tags: android-studio

Im trying to run `Clean and Rerun` feature in android studio with `cmd + control + r` but nothing happens.

[image]

Who can I test the shortcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used first the option on the menu, activated the option to use always the same device and then the shortcut worked. not sure why is not working as expected.